# Can't Create Record in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having issues creating a new record getting the error:

```
NoMethodError in CoffeeRoastsController#create
undefined method `name' for #<CoffeeBlend:0x007f95a0d168d8>
```

I'm trying to create a new `coffee_roast` which has_many `coffee_blends` which is a joins table which also has_many `coffee_beans`.  My `coffee_roast/_form.html.erb` has a collection select bringing through the various `coffee_beans`

**_form**

```
<%= form_with(model: coffee_roast, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if coffee_roast.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(coffee_roast.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this coffee_roast from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% coffee_roast.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

   <div class="col-6">
    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= form.label :roaster, class: 'control-label' %><br />
      <%= form.collection_select(:roaster_id, Roaster.order(:roaster_name), :id, :roaster_name, :prompt => 'Choose Roaster') %>
    </div>

  <div class="field">
    <strong><%= form.label :name %></strong>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :coffee_roast_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= collection_check_boxes :coffee_roast, :coffee_bean_ids, CoffeeBean.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :name do |cb| %>
    <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text } %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= collection_check_boxes :coffee_roast, :flavour_ids, Flavour.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :name do |cb| %>
      <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text } %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :style, "Style", class: 'control-label' %><br />
    <%= form.select :style, [ 'Espresso','Filter' ], :prompt => 'Select One', id: :coffee_style, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :strength, "Strength", class: 'control-label' %><br />
    <%= form.select :strength, [ 'Light','Medium','Dark' ], :prompt => 'Select One', id: :coffee_strength, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :image %>
    <%= form.file_field :image, id: :coffee_roast_image %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am able to create the record if I do not select any beans.

As the error says that `name` is an undefined method for CoffeeBlend, I'm suspecting I have something potential wrong in that collection_select, but I can't work out what it would be.

I'm able to create new coffee_beans, and hence update the coffee_blend joins table fine.

**The Models**

```
class CoffeeBlend < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :coffee_bean
    belongs_to :coffee_roast

class CoffeeBean < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :coffee_blends
    has_many :coffee_roasts, through: :coffee_blends
    belongs_to :country

class CoffeeRoast < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :roaster
    has_many :coffee_blends
    has_many :coffee_beans, through: :coffee_blends

    has_one_attached :image
```

**controller**

```
  def create
    @coffee_roast = CoffeeRoast.new(coffee_roast_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @coffee_roast.save
        format.html { redirect_to @coffee_roast, notice: 'Coffee roast was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @coffee_roast }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @coffee_roast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Console**

```
Started POST "/coffee_roasts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-04 08:17:05 +0000
Processing by CoffeeRoastsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+MbuyujdR1gSTRaylqeUjto4ZqhgnNnGfnPRiNEevdu2wePduXtEugbtmNpx6HGrtivFWZC92KGwTGJSy9+A2A==", "coffee_roast"=>{"roaster_id"=>"6", "name"=>"Revelation", "coffee_bean_ids"=>["", "4", "5"], "flavour_ids"=>["", "3", "2"], "style"=>"Espresso", "strength"=>"Dark"}, "commit"=>"Create Coffee roast"}
  CoffeeBean Load (44.8ms)  SELECT "coffee_beans".* FROM "coffee_beans" WHERE "coffee_beans"."id" IN ($1, $2)  [["id", 4], ["id", 5]]
  Flavour Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "flavours".* FROM "flavours" WHERE "flavours"."id" IN ($1, $2)  [["id", 3], ["id", 2]]
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  CoffeeRoast Exists (43.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "coffee_roasts" WHERE "coffee_roasts"."id" IS NOT NULL AND "coffee_roasts"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "revelation"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Roaster Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "roasters".* FROM "roasters" WHERE "roasters"."roaster_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["roaster_id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 280ms (ActiveRecord: 116.2ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for #<CoffeeBlend:0x007f95a3ad10e8>):
```

Comment: Could you please add full error backtrace and `create` action code?

Comment: Just added. Thanks

Comment: Does error backtrace points to line with `coffee_bean_ids` in the form partial? Try to change collection select to `form.collection_check_boxes :coffee_bean_ids, CoffeeBean.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :name do |cb|`

Comment: Do you mean remove `:coffee_roast,`?  This throws an error as too few arguments.

Comment: Please, note `form.collection_check_boxes`

Comment: Noted.  Exactly the same error however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186182/discussion-between-vasilisa-and-simon-cooper).

Comment: Please add code for coffee_roast_params and I am also assuming that CoffeeBlend class does not contain an attribute named "name"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vasilisa she spotted I was trying to create a `slug` in the `coffee_blend` joins table where there was no field called `:name`